# Can I add autoplay sound on ios or chrome devices?

Tags: html, audio-player, autoplay, autoplay-media-studio

I am trying to write code in html to autoplay sound in ios or chrome device, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the browser.

In general, sounds are blocked until the user has interacted with your page.

From MDN:

> Automatically starting the playback of audio (or videos with audio tracks) immediately upon page load can be an unwelcome surprise to users. While autoplay of media serves a useful purpose, it should be used carefully and only when needed.
> [Autoplay guide for media and Web Audio APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide)